# loadStrings from a single https URL sometime works sometimes doesn't

Tags: java, http, web, processing

I am trying to search a video post page from Musical.ly.  I made a test program that tests one video's webpage.  It works about 1/10 times.

I'm testing the exact same code on the exact same URL every time with no changes.

What should I change so it works every time?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

String url;
String[] lines;

void setup() {

///////////////////////URL///////////////////////
  url = "https://m.tiktok.com/v/6637213398008335622.html?u_code=e65hca7774483&preview_pb=6&language=en&timestamp=1549145463&utm_medium=ios&app=musically&tt_from=copy&user_id=312760327610474496&utm_source=copy&utm_campaign=client_share&copytype=1";
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

println("URL: ", url, "\n\n");

//search the page source
delay(10);
lines = loadStrings(url); //rarely loads everything it should
delay(10);
println("First line of page source: ", lines[0]);
exit();

}
```

It should show the first line of page source as:

#tunel #pool #hotwheels #race #gopro #water|hantaboi|TikTok|Global Video Community ...

However, it usually just shows:

||TikTok|Global Video Community ...

I have tried viewing the page source on my browser (Firefiox) and it works every time there.

URL:

https://m.tiktok.com/v/6637213398008335622.html?u_code=e65hca7774483&preview_pb=6&language=en&timestamp=1549145463&utm_medium=ios&app=musically&tt_from=copy&user_id=312760327610474496&utm_source=copy&utm_campaign=client_share&copytype=1

Comment: My guess is this is an issue with the server, not with Processing.

Comment: @KevinWorkman it works properly every time on firefox though...

Comment: I don't think that really tells you much. The server might be detecting the user agent or something and returning something different if you aren't in a valid browser. If I were you I would look for an API instead of trying to scrape the HTML.